# Laravel 5 24 hour loop application

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm trying to create a Laravel 5 application that executes a script once every 24 hours, as requested by a client. But since this application isn't supposed to respond to any HTTP requests, i'm not sure how to go about it. What i'm having problems with is the execution of the script, since it won't respond to any requests, how can i execute a script within the context of a Laravel application?

Is that even possible in this framework?

Comment: You could do task scheduling
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/scheduling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You COULD create a main loop in **PHP** and have your script keep running but sleep until it's time to execute your logic again. The downside is that memory management is a bit out of your hands in PHP so it might run out of memory, even if you manually advise the garbage collector to run.

A common solution on **Linux** is to set up a **CRON job** or on **Windows** use the **Windows Task Scheduler** to setup the script to run once every 24h.

Depending on the script you either run **PHP** in *CLI mode* and execute it like any other command line tool. Or you could run **CURL** or something similar to call a **URL** to execute your script.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel framework has inbuilt task schedular.
So you can use this feature to schedule the task that you want to run once every 24 hours.

Here is the documentation of how to create a cron job and create a task schedular using laravel https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/scheduling